# How to calculate median in eval_metric_ops?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I would like to use the median operation instead of the mean when evaluating my tensorflow model using the Estimator interface.

I use this operation in my model_function :

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, 
   eval_metric_ops={"accuracy": tf.metrics.mean(my_tensor)})
```

I didn't find a median function in the tf.metrics package to replace tf.metrics.mean. I can calculate it myself but eval_metric_ops requires a tuple of (tensor, update_op) and I am not sure what should be update_op. How to implement this metric myself?

Thanks!

edit:
I haven't found how to do it yet, but there was a discussion about it in the tensorflow github : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5837

So I will use instead this tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_concat to return the full array of accuracies on my eval dataset :

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops={"all_accuracies": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_concat(my_tensor)})
And use numpy to calculate the median :

evaluation = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=myinput_fn, mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL,steps=None)
print(np.median(evaluation['all_accuracies']))
I can get my final accuracy like that, but I won't see it during training on tensorboard, any idea on how to do it?